# Why didn't I earn the "Talkative" badge?

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, badges

The "Badges" page states that the requirement for earning the "Talkative" badge is

> Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more
>   starred, in chat

It seems that I fulfilled this requirement about 48 hours ago -- at the moment, I'm at 26 messages, with 1 starred (the "Herbert Voß comparison" one). At first I suspected that the badge would be awarded only with some delay (e.g. like tag badges, which seem to be awarded on the following day), but in the meantime other users (Joseph Wright, Andrew Stacey) have earned the "Talkative" badge, apparently shortly after getting their first starred chat message.

Is this a glitch in the badge award mechanism or did I miss something regarding the requirement for "Talkative"?

EDIT: As I'm now a candidate for community moderator, I checked the [candidate statistics site](http://se.awio.com/election.html), and it also doesn't list my (duly awarded) "Sportsmanship" badge. This looks more and more like a bug in some database.

EDIT 2: Okay, scrap that "Sportsmanship" problem. But I'd still like to be "Talkative". :-)

Comment: I was a bit bemused to be awarded that one, I don't feel like I've been very talkative!  Maybe it was an intercept and I got the one intended for you ...

Comment: I think you really earned your badge. :-) The thing is, being "Talkative" is one of the "Noteworthy Badges" for would-be moderators ...

Comment: @lockstep: You should nominate yourself even if you're not "Talkative"!

Comment: The missing sportsmanship badge looks like a bug on the candidate statistics site (which isn't run by stack overflow).

Comment: @lockstep: Caramdir seems to be right, as according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/61/sportsmanship I've also got that one, and it does not appear on the stats site list.

Comment: I got the "Sportsmanship" badge a few hours before candidating and it doesn't show up either.

Comment: I reported it now to Yi Jiang, the creator of the statistic page in the [related post on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/moderator-nomination-possibly-useful-statistics/75726#75726). I linked back to this post.

Comment: Ok, Yi Jiang already came back to me and told me that the data is live and it's not an API bug. He has a look on the missing badge. See the comments below [this post on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/moderator-nomination-possibly-useful-statistics/75726#75726) for more details.

Comment: It works now. Yi Jiang fixed it. You need to clear the browser cache (CTRL+F5) first.

Comment: Re talkatimve - I'm not at a PC at the moment, but I will investigate this when I can; it is on my list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that some of the behind-the-scenes code here is trying to use your network-wide unique identifier - but because you only have an account on tex, your unique identifier isn't published anywhere.

This is clearly an oversight; this is absolutely a scenario we fully support. I'm working on a fix; there is a fairly obvious workaround (visit another SE site), but I'd **really** rather you didn't - it would be nice to check the fixed code finds you.

Comment: As this issue has been right at the top of your list for two weeks, may I ask for the expected time frame to resolve it? ;-)

Comment: @lockstep updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your update -- I will refrain from visiting another SE site for now.

Comment: @lockstep - I have applied the change, and chat now knows your unique id. I've checked the "who has the badge", and you are now in the list. So you should get the badge in the next run - please let me know if it doesn't appear in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Many thanks -- it worked! (And I'm on my way to being "Outspoken". ;-)).